# Problems linking to a lib which implementation is inside a header file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I'm trying to compile a C++ source code which uses the lib [OpenRacm](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/817671/Unicamp/Mestrado/OpenRACM.tar.bz2). That lib is a modified version of OpenRacm from [here](http://sglab.kaist.ac.kr/~sungeui/OpenRACM/) to compile in the last version of Ubuntu and Mac OS X, apparently this lib was developed focusing mainly on Visual C++.

The source code I'm trying is [here](http://pastebin.com/nJcZEdw9), and trying to compile this way:

```
g++ source.cpp -o app -I../opencram/inc/ -L../opencram/Lib/ -lOpenRACM -g
```

Which gives this [error](http://pastebin.com/J0C1Eec9)

I think it's because the file mem_manager.h doesn't have mem_manager.cpp, i.e., it implements all its functionality inside the header file. The question is: There is a way to compile my source code without split the mem_manager.h in interface (header file) and implementation (CPP file)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the opencram paths a typo (should be openracm)?

Comment: Yes, it should be. Here at my machine I named the folder wrongly as opencram, it's a typo, but not the source of problem. Thanks.

Comment: @tfmoraes I have the same problem as you.How did you solve it?Thanks.

Comment: @lads unfortunately, I don't remember what I've done to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your problem is that you have not supplied the import library (.a) to the linker. Make sure that the .a file that comes with OpenRacm is passed to the linker.

Comment: There is no .lib file, only libOpenRACM.a which contains a lot of .o files. How can I generate this .lib file? Thanks!

Comment: My mistake. Didn't spot that you are on *nix. On *nix the import library is typically a .a file. You don't generate anything. You just give the .a file to the linker.